# Android : test if a device can access the internet

Tags: android

In my android app, I would like to test if a user can access the internet. I know I able to test if he is connected to wifi or 3G/4G, etc... but maybe the user is connected to a local network and doesn't have access to the internet.

Should I try a "ping" to google to be sure that he can download anything or does it exist a function which ensure the phone has internet ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if Android device has Internet connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493517/detect-if-android-device-has-internet-connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check whether the user has access to internet while s/he has connection, try to reach a web site like google with some timeout.

```
    URL url = new URL("https://google.com");

    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 30);
    urlc.connect();
    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        return true;
    }
```

If you get timeout or an error code, you can assume your app is not connected to internet.

Comment: Okay, this seems to be good. I'll test your code. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
      = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
```

}

AndroidManifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

But it's already been answered here :

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442893/android-networkinfo-always-returns-true-even-if-internet-is-not-available. isConnected() return true even if the user is connected to a local network only. This is the problem I wanna avoid.